# PHP/XPATH - Find PRECEDING-SIBLING of PARENT and get its' CHILD

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I've been trying to figure this our for days, but I simply cannot seem to get it to work.

Let's say I have an XML file named `test.xml` like this:

```
<root>
    <itemList>
        <item>
            <name>A</name>
            <type>AAA</type>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>B</name>
            <type>BBB</type>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>C</name>
            <type>CCC</type>
        </item>
    </itemList>
</root>
```

From PHP, I use `SimpleXMLElement` to find the node with text `BBB`.

```
<?php 
$xmlStr = file_get_contents('test.xml');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr);
$res = $xml->xpath('//type[contains(text(), "BBB")]/parent::*');

echo "{$res[0]->name} ({$res[0]->type})";
// Result: B (BBB)
```

Now, I'd like to find the `preceding-sibling` node of the `parent`, and get the `child` nodes' values like `A (AAA)`, but I simply can't figure out how to do so.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the nearest preceding sibling, use this XPath query:

```
//type[contains(text(), "BBB")]/parent::item/preceding-sibling::item[1]
```

You need to set the predicate to 1 so as to pick the nearest of the siblings. Otherwise you'd always get the first sibling (for example, if you remove the `[1]` predicate, you'll get the `AAA` element for both `BBB` and `CCC`)

Note that the wildcards are not necessary since you presumably already know what the tags are.

```
$xml = "<root>
    <itemList>
        <item>
            <name>A</name>
            <type>AAA</type>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>B</name>
            <type>BBB</type>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>C</name>
            <type>CCC</type>
        </item>
    </itemList>
</root>";

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$res = $xml->xpath('//type[contains(text(), "BBB")]/parent::item/preceding-sibling::item[1]');
echo "{$res[0]->name} ({$res[0]->type})".PHP_EOL;

$res = $xml->xpath('//type[contains(text(), "CCC")]/parent::item/preceding-sibling::item[1]');
echo "{$res[0]->name} ({$res[0]->type})";
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/kcl38)

*Result*

> A (AAA)
>   B (BBB)

To further illustrate the need to use the predicate, take a look at this:

```
$xml = "<root>
    <itemList>
        <item>
            <name>A</name>
            <type>AAA</type>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>B</name>
            <type>BBB</type>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>C</name>
            <type>CCC</type>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>C</name>
            <type>DDD</type>
        </item>
    </itemList>
</root>";

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$res = $xml->xpath('//type[contains(text(), "DDD")]/parent::item/preceding-sibling::item');
var_dump($res);
```

*Result*

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[2]
      public 'name' => string 'A' (length=1)
      public 'type' => string 'AAA' (length=3)
  1 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[3]
      public 'name' => string 'B' (length=1)
      public 'type' => string 'BBB' (length=3)
  2 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[4]
      public 'name' => string 'C' (length=1)
      public 'type' => string 'CCC' (length=3)
```

See how, no matter which element you select with the query, the farthest sibling is *always* first in the list (and the closest the last)? So, to simulate using the predicate, you could also get the closest sibling simply picking the last element in the array (notice there's no `[1]` predicate):

```
$res = $xml->xpath('//type[contains(text(), "DDD")]/parent::item/preceding-sibling::item');
$total = count($res);
echo "{$res[$total - 1]->name} ({$res[$total - 1]->type})".PHP_EOL;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/1oYIi)

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This was exactly what I needed. :)

Comment: @LilisSkyremix it's no problem man. I added another example to further clarify the need for a predicate, and an alternative as well. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

See demo https://implode.io/q9OOSC

```
$xmlStr = <<<XML
<root>
    <itemList>
        <item>
            <name>A</name>
            <type>AAA</type>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>B</name>
            <type>BBB</type>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>C</name>
            <type>CCC</type>
        </item>
    </itemList>
</root>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr);

$res = $xml->xpath('//type[contains(text(), "BBB")]/parent::*/preceding-sibling::*');

echo "{$res[0]->name} ({$res[0]->type})";
```